# e.Cancel evento en wpf

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf, axml

Sabe alguien como sustituir el `e.Cancel` de Windows Forms en WPF?.

Lo que necesito es que el `TextBox` no pierda el foco si no escribe el dato correctamente.

No hay algo que funcione igual en WPF?

Gracias.

Comment: Hay diferentes opciones para devolver el foco al textbox dependiendo de si usas mvvm, y de que estes usando para validar el contenido.

Comment: Sé que esta pregunta es antigua, pero ¿Cómo haces la validación en el TextBox?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
 private void textbox1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        if (textbox1.Text == "a") //Condición que quieras
        {
            var restoreFocus = (System.Threading.ThreadStart)delegate { textbox1.Focus(); };
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(restoreFocus);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Los más parecido al e.Cancel de Winforms en WPF es e.Handled. Si lo seteas e.Handled = true;, te funcionará.